# Updating a single line on a text file with a Java method

Tags: java

I know previous questions LIKE this one have been asked, but this question has to do with the specifics of the code that I have written. I am trying to update a single line of code on a file that will be permanently updated even when the program terminates so that the data can be brought up again. The method that I am writing currently looks like this (no compile errors found with eclipse)

```
public static void editLine(String fileName, String name, int element,
            String content) throws IOException {
        try {
            // Open the file specified in the fileName parameter.
            FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    fStream));
            String strLine;
            StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();

            // Read line by line.
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String tokens[] = strLine.split(" ");
                if (tokens.length > 0) {
                    if (tokens[0].equals(name)) {
                        tokens[element] = content;
                        String newLine = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1] + " "
                                + tokens[2];
                        fileContent.append(newLine);
                        fileContent.append("\n");
                    } else {
                        fileContent.append(strLine);
                        fileContent.append("\n");
                    }
                }

                /*
                 * File Content now has updated content to be used to override
                 * content of the text file
                 */
                FileWriter fStreamWrite = new FileWriter(fileName);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fStreamWrite);
                out.write(fileContent.toString());
                out.close();

                // Close InputStream.
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("COULD NOT UPDATE FILE!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

If you could look at the code and let me know what you would suggest, that would be wonderful, because currently I am only getting my catch message.

Comment: Can you change your code so it prints out the full exception before the catch message?

Comment: Read everything in. Write everything out.

Comment: You're ignoring the exception, and thus don't know why you got it. Remove the ctach block completely, or at least add `e.printStackTrace()` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. First off the bat, `StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();` is bad practice as this file could well be larger than the user's available memory. You should not keep much of the file in memory at all. Do this by reading into a buffer, processing the buffer (adjusting it if necessary), and writing the buffer to a new file. When done, delete the old file and rename the secondary to the old one's name. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is a really good answer to this question. It helped me see how to see outside the box.

Comment: Thanks for the recognition. Your comment counts as '+1' or 'thanks', something StackOverflow seeks to not have in the comments. I won't flag this as you're new to the site.